# Preventing Previous Pages to be shown after Logout without disabling Browser Back Button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a software in which logout functionality is assigned to me. I am trying to develop code for LogOut Functionality. I tried everything, but after clicking browser back button the previous pages are shown.

Here is my Controller

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: you can navigate using location.replace

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+all+pages+from+history+after+logout+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: you can check if session not exist then  disable redirect back , just reload the  page on back button